# in linux,hyphen is a multi-character character?

Tags: c, linux, unicode

I use the c program try to count words from a text.But when the text is `man malloc >x`,the hyphen also is printed.
finally ,i find the hyphen is a multi-character character.
who can tell me the hyphen's ascii.
it's about in line 17 in `man malloc >x`.

Comment: "Line 17"? My `man` viewer repaginates according to my terminal size...

Comment: Why not paste the character in question here?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen): The hyphen should not be confused with dashes (‒, –, —, ―) ... or with the minus sign (−)

Comment: The hyphen "-" is 2D in the ASCII standard, which is most definitely one byte/character.

Comment: "-" not an hyphen, but a dash, the hyphen is "–". Cf the wikipedia page.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if you don't give the character, we can't know what it is. A man page is always reformated, and modified to fit the context of displaying.

> *i find the hyphen is a multi-character character. who can tell me the hyphen's ascii.*

if it's a multi-character character, then it's not ASCII, it's unicode. And my guess is that it's:

```
‐
```

which is unicode character 8208. Hint, in python3 run:

```
>>> print(ord('–'))
8208
```

now to handle that, you need to include `wchar.h`, use a `wchar_t*` string and count the characters using `wcslen()`. As you like to read manuals:

- [`man wcslen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcslen)

as a snippet:

```
const wchar_t* s = "This is an hyphen: `–` !";
printf("%d", wcslen(s));
```

N.B.: to avoid hyphenization of words in your manpage displaying, you may want to setup your `COLUMNS` env variable to a very large value ;-)

N.B.2: you may also want to use `nroff -mandoc /usr/share/man/man3/malloc.3` and look at nroff options to better fit your usage, and avoid hyphenization.

Comment: `'–'` is U+2013, EN DASH. The character I see when I do `man malloc > x` is `'‐'`, U+2010, HYPHEN. It appears when words are split across lines. (But with different locale settings, `man` uses `'-'`, U+002D, HYPHEN-MINUS, which is an ASCII character.)

Comment: ok, I fixed the unicode value in my answer, though it does not change it much otherwise. As I said as introduction, *a man page is reformatted and modified to fid the context of displaying* which is what you're confirming ;-)

Comment: MALLOC(3)                                      Linux Programmer's Manual                                     MALLOC(3)



NAME
       calloc, malloc, free, realloc - Allocate and free dynamic memory

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>

       void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
       void *malloc(size_t size);
       void free(void *ptr);
       void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);

DESCRIPTION
       calloc()  allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the **allo鈥?       cated** memory.  The

Comment: what happened? did you collapse while making a comment?